# TypeError: can't concat bytes to str, then, TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes

Tags: python

Learning Python lately, and I'm trying to do a small practice. Then this errors shows up.

```
  File "/Users/Alexis/.spyder-py3/temp.py", line 29, in <module>
    f.write(txt+'\n')

TypeError: can't concat bytes to str
```

Could anyone tell me what's going on wrong here, please?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

r=requests.get(url='http://news.qq.com/world_index.shtml')
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')
f=open('/Users/Alexis/Desktop/news.text','w')
f.seek(0)

f.write('Today News')

    news=soup.find_all('a',href=re.compile('http://news.qq.com/a/20170307/'))

for i in news:
    txt=i.text.encode('utf-8').strip()
    if txt=='':
        continue
    else:
        u=i.attrs['href']
        ur=requests.get(url=u)
        usoup=BeautifulSoup(ur.text,'lxml')
        f.write(txt+'\n')
        f.write('Text:\n')

        p=usoup.find('div',id='Cnt-Main-Article-QQ').find_all('p')
        for i in p:            
            f.write(i.text+'\n')

    break

f.close()
print('Finish')
```

I've tried a few different methods

I have tried

```
f.write(txt+'\n'.encode('ascii'))

TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes
f.write(txt+'\n'.encode('utf-8'))

TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes
```

Thanks for help!!

Comment: Why are you encoding `i.text` to UTF-8 at all? If you don't encode `txt`, it'll be a `str` object and you can concatenate more text just fine, **and** write it to your text file without having to decode again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `f.write(str(txt)+'\n', 'utf-8') #or whichever way you are encoding`

From your error message, `write()` wants a string, but you are giving it bytes, hence, you must call `str()` to convert txt to str type.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? Why do you think this is the solution?

Comment: I apologize for being terse! Should this be explanation enough? @Matthias

Comment: This explains how to get rid of the error, but the main reason for the problem is, that `txt` was encoded to UTF-8 before and there is no reason for that.

Comment: Now it says, TypeError: write() takes exactly one argument (2 given)

Answer (score 0):

Try following.
f.write(txt.decode()+'\n')